# Fastest way to synchronize work between a generating and consuming process in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

**Update 1**: It seems like BlockingCollection suggested below is the perfect fit, and I will try to apply that first thing tomorrow.  Thank you for the replies.

**Update 2**: Indeed it seems to perform admirably.  Thanks again for all the help.
__

I have a scientific application in C# with two internal tasks that need to communicate:

Tasks:
**(a)** rapidly acquires a large dataset (some times larger than memory), **(b)** processes each entry.

To prevent getting the entire dataset at once, I plan for (a) to take some amount of data at a time, then for (b) to process all of that, and repeat until done.  (a) and (b) both have multiple threads, but are in the same executable.

The data comes out of (a) in form of a list of small individually processable chunks, so I'm wondering the speediest strategy to keep this dance going between the two processes in C# (Windows .NET Standard), and wonder if anyone has experience that can help this decision? I plan is either to:

- Have a list in A that B acquires a lock{} on at say 1000 entries, to stop processes in A from adding more data while processing is done.
- Have A send B a event when the list is over say 1000, and then have B stop A's threads while it processes.

I not a very experience programmer when it comes to these things, and wonder if anyone has insights that may help, or some terms I can google for to clarify?  (: Help is appreciated (:

Comment: It seems to me a "producer/consumer pattern".just google it there are many ways to implement it

Comment: Please take a look at [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, the BlockingCollection truly seems like a perfect match for what I am trying to do (:

Comment: For more information take a look [pipelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a queue (lets call that Q).

For A:

```
queueLimit = 1000

while A has data {

    // Wait until Q length is decreased
    // Wait until B removes data from Q
    while Q.length > queueLimit {
        sleep
    }

    // Add data to Q when B is < 1000
    Q.addData(data)
}
```

For B:

```
while Q has data {

    data = getAndRemoveFromQ() // Q's length will decrease
    process data
}
```

Basically that's how. But you have to implement locking. Q could be a class with methods `pop()` and `add()`

Or use the [Queue Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) mechanism for cross thread data processing!

One thread can push into the queue all the work that needs to be done, while another can loop to wait until the queue has data.

Comment: Instead of ConcurrentQueue, a BlockingCollection is even better for this kind of job and uses a ConcurrentQueue as it's internal store by default.

Comment: Yeah - it is - didn't see the comment about the blocking collection - queue is really easy to implement though!

Comment: And doing `foreach(var item in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())` isnt? Also how are you going to handle not spinning and wasting a CPU at 100% when the queue is empty with just ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: It is more likely that someone will understand the concept of a queue over a blocking collection! But if your answer is spot on - then post it....